# A variant symbol of p letter

Tags: fonts, symbols

How can I create such variant of p letter in Latex?

BTW, what is the name of such a symbol?

[image: p variant]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
    \(\mathscr{P}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not really a symbol, it's just the letter P, but in 'Script' font. See http://www.stat.colostate.edu/~vollmer/pdfs/typesetting-script.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The  `rsfso` variant looks nicer, in my opinion, and it can be scaled:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr, scaled=1.1]{rsfso}%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\begin{document}

If $ \abs{X} = n$, $\abs[\big]{\mathscr{P}(X) } = 2^n $.

\end{document}
```

[image]